# Reading Mac .numbers file from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, macos

I've been doing a bunch of research and testing but haven't found a way to read a Mac .numbers file.  I'm currently using Pandas to read CSV and Excel files and was hoping I could also use it to read `.numbers` files but I haven't seen anything in their docs either.

I've noticed a few posts about this on StackOverflow but they all recommend you convert the file to CSV first which I don't want to do.  I need to read the file directly as I do with Excel, I can't do any file conversion.  Is this something that can be done with Python or with Pandas?

Comment: Not sure if it's the conversion you want to avoid or the CSV, but maybe LibreOffice `unoconv` or `soffice` can do `Numbers->XLSX` without CSV.

Comment: @MarkSetchell This could be a possible solution but you are correct, it's the conversion I'm looking to avoid.  I'm working with users who are not technical so I would like for them to hand over the `Numbers` file directly without asking them to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

A Python module ([numbers-parser](https://pypi.org/project/numbers-parser/)) is there for parsing Apple Numbers files. It supports and is tested against Python versions from 3.8 onwards.

Ex: A file is having salary as 0 for user_id 4 (column 3rd). We need to create a new file with updated value 4000.

[image: my_spreadsheet.numbers]
[image: my_spreadsheet_update.numbers]

```
from numbers_parser import Document

doc = Document("my_spreadsheet.numbers")
sheets = doc.sheets
tables = sheets[0].tables
data = tables[0]
print(type(data.rows()))  # <class 'list'>
row_data = data.rows()
new_salary = 4000
for count, each_row in enumerate(row_data):
    if each_row[1].value == 4:
        data.write(count, 2, new_salary)
doc.save("my_spreadsheet_update.numbers")
```